# SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure - 2Way SSL

Tags: java, ssl, handshake

I wrote an Http Client using Apache HttpClient 4.1.13 which call a remote HTTP service using 2way-ssl.

I configured:

- keystore.jks : contains the private key and the client certificate
- keystore password: the password of keystore.jks
- truststore.jks: contains the certificate of CA e intermediate CA of the server
- truststore password: the password of truststore.jks

the code:

```
        KeyStore keyStore  = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(new File(keystore));
        try {
            keyStore.load(instream, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
        } finally {
            instream.close();
        }
    
    
        KeyStore trustStore  = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        instream = new FileInputStream(new File(trustore));
        try {
            trustStore.load(instream, trustorePassword.toCharArray());
        } finally {
            instream.close();
        }


        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
                .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray())
                .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                .build();
       

        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                sslContext,
                new String[] {"TLSv1.1","TLSv1.2"},
                null,
                SSLConnectionSocketFactory.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
                    
        poolingConnManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(
                RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.INSTANCE)
                .register("https", sslsf)
                .build());
```

If I run a java main (**JDK Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11**) which does the call, I got a successful connection and I see in the logs

```
[2022-01-25 17:49:18][][][][][main][DEBUG]o.a.h.c.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Secure session established
[2022-01-25 17:49:18][][][][][main][DEBUG]o.a.h.c.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
[2022-01-25 17:49:18][][][][][main][DEBUG]o.a.h.c.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
[2022-01-25 17:49:18][][][][][main][DEBUG]o.a.h.c.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  peer principal: XXXXX
[2022-01-25 17:49:18][][][][][main][DEBUG]o.a.h.c.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  peer alternative names: [YYYYY]
[2022-01-25 17:49:18][][][][][main][DEBUG]o.a.h.c.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  issuer principal: XXXXX
```

If I run the same code with the same keystores and passwords in Docker **OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_252-b09))** I got the following handshake error

```
http-nio-8080-exec-1, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
http-nio-8080-exec-1, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
%% Invalidated:  [Session-2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
http-nio-8080-exec-1, called closeSocket()
http-nio-8080-exec-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:   Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
[2022-01-25 16:47:45][SESSION_NOT_INITIALIZED][10.60.168.202][http-nio-8080-exec-1]   [DEBUG]o.a.h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: Shutdown connection
[2022-01-25 16:47:45][SESSION_NOT_INITIALIZED][10.60.168.202][http-nio-8080-exec-1]   [DEBUG]o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Connection discarded
```

What should I search ? Any hints?

**UPDATE**:
The keystore contains the private key and the certificate chain : **certificate -> intermediate CA -> Root CA**; I don't understand why the client doesn't find the right certificate to send to the server.

In the working test I got this log

```
*** ServerHelloDone
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
matching alias: 1
*** Certificate chain
```

In the failed test I got:

```
*** ServerHelloDone
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client  authentication
*** Certificate chain
```

Comment: Your second log is obviously from `javax.net.debug=ssl[:suboptions]`; a few screenfuls before the part you posted it should show if the client is finding/choosing a cert&key entry for client auth, and sending Certificate and CertificateVerify around ClientKeyExchange. If it didn't do so, that's probably the problem. If it did so but not correctly, that _might_ be your problem, although the server _should_ use a better alert code for that case. Otherwise it's something else.

Comment: Yes, it seems there is no matching between Server Certificate Request and the Client certificate. But I don't understand why ... the 2 tests uses the identical keystore and trustore!

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake and the problem was in totally different point.
The above code was right.